# Concatenate spark data frame column with its rows in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying build a string by concatenating values from a data frame.
For example:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("20181001","10"),     
  ("20181002","40"),
  ("20181003","50")).toDF("Date","Key")
df.show
```

Output of the DF is like below.

[image]

Here I want to build the condition based on the values of the data frame, such as: (Date=20181001 and key=10) or (Date=20181002 and key=40) or (Date=20181003 and key=50) and so on..The generated condition will serve as input for another process. Here the columns in the data frame can be dynamic.

The below snippet I am trying and it is forming the string as needed but its a static one.Also not very sure how it will perform when i have to generate the condition for more than 10 columns. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

```
val df = Seq(
  ("20181001","10"),     
  ("20181002","40"),
  ("20181003","50")).toDF("Date","Key")

val colList = df.columns
var cond1 = ""
var finalCond =""
for (row <- df.rdd.collect)
 {
    cond1 = "("
    var pk = row.mkString(",").split(",")(0)
    cond1 = cond1+colList(0)+"="+pk
    var ak = row.mkString(",").split(",")(1)
    cond1 = cond1 +" and " + colList(1)+ "=" +ak +")"
    finalCond = finalCond + cond1 + " or " 
    cond1= ""    
 }
 print("Condition:" +finalCond.dropRight(3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check this DF solution.

```
scala> val df = Seq(
       |   ("20181001","10"),
       |   ("20181002","40"),
       |   ("20181003","50")).toDF("Date","Key")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Date: string, Key: string]

scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("gencond",concat(lit("(Date="), 'Date, lit(" and Key=") ,'Key,lit(")")))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Date: string, Key: string ... 1 more field]


scala> df2.agg(collect_list('gencond)).show(false)
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|collect_list(gencond)                                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[(Date=20181001 and Key=10), (Date=20181002 and Key=40), (Date=20181003 and Key=50)]|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**EDIT1**

You can read them from parquet files and just change the names as in this solution. In the final step, again replace the names from the parquet header.
Check this.

```
scala> val df = Seq(("101","Jack"),("103","wright")).toDF("id","name")  // Original names from parquet
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, name: string]

scala> val df2= df.select("*").toDF("Date","Key")  // replace it with Date/Key as we used in this question
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Date: string, Key: string]

scala> val df3 = df2.withColumn("gencond",concat(lit("(Date="), 'Date, lit(" and Key=") ,'Key,lit(")")))
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Date: string, Key: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val df4=df3.agg(collect_list('gencond).as("list"))
df4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [list: array<string>]

scala> df4.select(concat_ws(" or ",'list)).show(false)
+----------------------------------------------------+
|concat_ws( or , list)                               |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|(Date=101 and Key=Jack) or (Date=103 and Key=wright)|
+----------------------------------------------------+

scala> val a = df.columns(0)
a: String = id

scala> val b = df.columns(1)
b: String = name

scala>  df4.select(concat_ws(" or ",'list).as("new1")).select(regexp_replace('new1,"Date",a).as("colx")).select(regexp_replace('colx,"Key",b).as("colxy")).show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------+
|colxy                                             |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|(id=101 and name=Jack) or (id=103 and name=wright)|
+--------------------------------------------------+


scala>
```

Comment: Awesome!! But how to make the columns dynamic instead of hard coded?

Comment: Are you asking about "df" values ? - you can have a csv file and just read them using spark.read.csv("csv_file") which gives you the dataframe

Comment: i used to create the df based on the parquet files and get those conditions from a json file and it is assumed the columns mentioned (in this case, Date and Key) in the JSON is there in the df. So I need to build the condition based on the columns available in the JSON and those are available to me as a List.

Comment: got you.. check my EDIT1

Answer (score 0):

Calling collect pulls the result back to the driver program so if you have a huge DataFrame you may well run out of memory.

If you are sure you are only dealing with a smallish number of rows that isn't a problem.

You could do something like:

```
df.map(row => s"($Date={row.getString(0)} and Key=${row.getString(1)})").collect.mkString("Condition: ", " or ", "")
```

Output:

```
res2: String = Condition: (Date=20181001 and Key=10) or (Date=20181002 and Key=40) or (Date=20181003 and Key=50)
```

Comment: Thank you.. Your solution is working fine.Bust changed little bit.df.rdd.map(row => s"({Date=${row.getString(0)} and Key=${row.getString(1)})").collect.mkString("Condition: ", " or ", "")

Answer (score 0):

Using `udf` you can do for variable number of `columns` like below

```
val list=List("Date","Key")

def getCondString(row:Row):String={
    "("+list.map(cl=>cl+"="+row.getAs[String](cl)).mkString(" and ")+")"
  }

val getCondStringUDF=udf(getCondString _)
df.withColumn("row", getCondStringUDF(struct(df.columns.map(df.col(_)):_*))).select("row").rdd.map(_(0).toString()).collect().mkString(" or ")
```